# In JavaScript, is there a way to get closure parameters

Tags: javascript, compilation, closures

I have two file:

```
//------------a.js--------------

function a(){
  return '1'
}

var testCase = {
  func(){
    return a()
  }
}

module.exports = testCase

//------------b.js--------------

var testCase = require('./a.js')

//Can I get closure parameters(function a) that not modify a.js?
```

Is there a way to get closure parameters In JavaScript? Thank You!

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the parameters of the function a() like get a and b from function a(a, b)?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. The function 'a' in your example is closed over, but it does not contain any parameters. If it did, you would have to return them or otherwise send them somewhere else (via another function), within function 'a's body.

Comment: It looks like you want to get a reference to `a` from `b.js`? You can't without modifying `a.js`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to return the list of parameters from a closure like get x and y from closure run(x, y) {} which is inside function walk() {} then the below code might help.

```
    function walk() {
        function run(x, y) {
            return x + y;
        }

        return run;
    }

    var fun = walk();

    fun.getParameters = function () {
        var functionText = this.prototype.constructor.toString();

        return functionText
            .substring(functionText.indexOf('(') + 1, functionText.indexOf(')'))
            .split(',')
            .map(x => x.trim());
    };

    console.log(fun.getParameters());
```